# MongoDB multi document transaction, reading non commited data

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Until `MongoDB v4.0`, multi document transactions were achieved by implementing a two phase commit.
After `4.0`, MongoDB has introduced the multi-document transactions for replica sets; As per their documentation; "until a transaction is committed, no write/update operations in the transaction are visible outside the transaction".
But what about the visibility of the data within the transaction scope?
For the sake of simplicity, I have implemented the example below, that depicts the case.

```
            var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
            var session = client.StartSession();
            var ColA = session.Client.GetDatabase("Testing").GetCollection<BsonDocument>("ColA");
            JObject Obj = new JObject();
            Obj.Add("A", "ValA");
            session.StartTransaction();
            ColA.InsertOne(session, BsonDocument.Parse(Obj.ToString()));
            var tt = ColA.Find(new BsonDocument { }).ToList();
            session.CommitTransaction();
```

In the origin, `"ColA"` is an empty collection, when I insert the document and then try to query it `(tt = ColA.Find...)`, the result set is still empty.
I understand that outside the transaction scope, the result set should remain empty until commit, but why is it empty inside the scope.

By reproducing the same scenario on SQL server, using the same logic, querying a table after an insertion within a transaction scope, returns data before commit.

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that the Mongo driver caches the `InsertOne` without committing it to disk, but the read operation tries to get the data from the disk before it is written? What happens if you delay the `Find` for a second or two? It's been a while since I touched MongoDB.

Comment: Delaying the operation does not affect the end result

Comment: As mickl point out below, you need to pass the session object into each and every operation, which can be easy to miss. If you don't feel like doing this, JohnKnoop.MongoRepository provides an abstraction that automatically enlists with the current transaction: https://github.com/johnknoop/MongoRepository#transactions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works as you expected, the only thing you're missing in your code is `session` passed as an argument to `Find` method, try:

```
session.StartTransaction();
ColA.InsertOne(session, BsonDocument.Parse(Obj.ToString()));
var tt = ColA.Find(session, Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Empty).ToList();

session.CommitTransaction();
```

Comment: Do we have a way around reading uncommitted documents outside a transaction?